# How to provide option to preview file before download

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I am using github-pages and jekyll to serve my own blog, where sometimes I put script files (python, MATLAB etc...) for the readers to download. Can I provide the readers with an option to preview the code file as text before they download it? I am imagining a scenario like when they click the hyperlink, instead of instantly downloading it, they are shown a page to view the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could host your code snippets as [GitHub Gists](http://gist.github.com/), then link to the Gists on your blog so that users could view your code and optionally download it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the file as a `.txt` file and then have 2 buttons or links: `Download File`, `Preview File`. You can either copy/paste into a new `.txt` file or Save As and add the `.txt` extension. Either way, you'll end up with the original file and then the `.txt` version of it.

For example, if you have `test.py`, then you can have the download link go to `test.py` and the preview link go to `test.py.txt`. The browser should render the `.txt` file as plaintext.